# Problem with subscriber a string

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried to do the tutorial writing a simple publisher and subscriber in c++ and it works.
Now i must use a function with argument the string that was subscribed, but i received the error: argument incorrect.
This is the code:

> void chatterCallback (const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
> ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]\n", msg->data.c_str());
> my_function(msg->data); //error
> // i also tried msg->data.c_str()
> }
> void my_function(char* c) ....

any suggestion?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54770/problem-with-subscriber-a-string/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-09**:
What is the signature of my_function?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-09**:
Also relevant: Does my_function need a non-const char* or is the just an old-style definition. If it doesn't change it, you could get away with just passing in the string data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

msg->data is of type string and ur function input argument is of type char*. Therefore u cannot directly pass either msg->data or msg->data.c_str() as argument and since u cannot change ur function argument i suggest following.
Add this to ur subscriber callback

char *c;
c=new char[sizeof(msg->data)];
c=&what[0];
myfunction(c)

This should work.

PS.Let me know if this doesnt work or any of the assumptions i made regarding ur problem is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-09**:
This looks like a memory leak to me. You are reassigning the pointer to c and forgetting the newly allocated memory. In addition sizeof does NOT return the length of the string.

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-09**:
I think you're looking for the `strcpy` function; just re-assigning the pointer won't change anything.

**Comment by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on 2013-02-09**:
thanks i tried strcpy(c,msg->data.c_str()); myfunction(c); and now work, because strcpy convert const char* to char*.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-02-11**:
@mrpiccolo please accept this answer using the checkmark on the left side so others know your question is resolved.